# Select attribute of table based on min value from another table

Tags: php, sql, select, sql-order-by, limit

My table structure is

[image: Table structure]

I want to get the recent video uploaded of the user

What I want to do is:

> "select video_id of a record who is having minimum of timestamp where userid='something'"

What I currently have is:

```
$recent_video = "$db->query("
  SELECT video_id 
  FROM video_primary 
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 
  WHERE userid = '$userid'"
) or die($db->error);"`


while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($recent_video))
{
  $video_id=$row['video_id'];
}
echo $video_id;
```

My table data is

[image: table data]

How do I get the most recent view uploaded by the user?

Comment: You should tag this question with MySQL instead SQL.

Comment: i'll rememberthat !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$recent_video=$db->query("select video_id from video_primary where userid='$userid' 
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 ") or die($db->error);
```

instead of

```
$recent_video="$db->query("select video_id from video_primary ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1 where userid='$userid'") or die($db->error);"
```

you are using where clause after order by and limit 1 which is a syntax error. see tutorial

[**Tutorial**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/select.html)

Answer (score 2):

Write `WHERE` clause after `FROM` part

Try this:

```
SELECT vp.video_id 
FROM video_primary vp
WHERE userid='$userid'
ORDER BY vp.timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific sequence of every clause in Query statement. Below is the sequence:

- Select
- Where
- Order by
- Limit

So, as per the above sequence, you should correct your query like below. Also, you should place double quote(") correctly.

`$recent_video = $db->query("
  SELECT video_id 
  FROM video_primary 
  WHERE userid = '$userid'
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"
) or die($db->error);`